# How does the browser traverse the DOM tree to apply the correct styles?

Tags: html, css, dom, flexbox

This question arose when I was thinking about how flexbox works when you have `flex-basis: auto`.

From my understanding, the browser would have to know the dimensions of the children who may also need to fetch the dimensions of their children and so on down the tree.

My guess is that the browser traverses back up the tree with the proper dimensions to apply the correct styles.

There are certain situations where I think the browser doesn't know the flexbox container's dimensions, so it delegates how much to grow or shrink to the parent element. But these are all assumptions I made up. Would be cool to see some legitimate explanation.

Comment: Actually the direct descendants of the flex container (`display:flex`) are the only elements that behave like flex-items.

Comment: @zer00ne Right, that's what I meant by they may need to fetch their children's dimensions. I probably should have clarified, such as when the current element has a display of flex and the children and so on.

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Render_tree_construction  (TL;DR: it's very complicated)